# Global Audit Table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, logging, database-performance, database-security

While looking at some tables in my schema, it occured to me if I could create a global audit table, which might contain some information on DML entries on all tables. I'd like to store `'Table name', 'Modifier', 'Row Update/Insert/Delete query', 'query result', 'Modifying Instance Information: sql-client, session-info(?)', performance items, timestamp, etc`. I could also limit this table-size by limiting number of rows through a `insert trigger` on this table through `rowcount`. Is this construct allowed? Is this a bad idea? What is the fastest it could get? What more problems does construct like this present? Basically, is direct logging into database a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging DML with `database level trigger` on big data and `bulk insert/update/delete` have a performance issue, so there is three other option :

1. SQL server Change Tracking : [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. Build-in data changes function (CDC) : [more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb522489(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
3. Database level Audit Log : [more info](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/security-create-and-view-audit-logs)

And i strongly preferred option no 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had a bike crash the evening later, so I couldn't get to see it. I shall read about the respective topics.

Comment: @user2338150; that's ok

Comment: @user2338150 are you ok now? its been almost  4 years?

Comment: @JasonLokiSmith thank you! i am fine! i just haven't got much to write over the last couple of years or so. but i am working on learning rust. it looks like a wonderful language.